# No internet through Wi-Fi after standby

Tags: network, wifi, internet

When my MacBook Air 11” 2015 (macOS Menterey 12.7.1) starting after sleep it still connected to Wi-Fi connection but doesn’t have any internet. Also it shows “connected to “wifiname” with IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx” in settings.
Reconnecting to spot or requesting dhcp address makes internet work but this not solution I want.

[image: wifi icon after sleep]

Comment: I doubt it shows "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" as the IP address it has.  Do you control the wifi network it is connecting to?  It sounds like whatever router is expiring out the connection, since renegotiating a DHCP lease makes it work again.

Comment: Does this issue occur on any other devices connected to the Wi-Fi?

Comment: @StackQsUp no. only Mac problem

Comment: @MarcWilson I've tried a lot of variants on router settings. making static dhcp-ip to mac-address(also it means ip will never expire) not helped. Mac shows in local network, can ping other devices, but internet doesn't appear

Comment: If you boot the Mac into recovery mode (restart and hold Command-R while booting), does the Internet work there? You can check by using Safari

Comment: Or if you have an Apple Silicon, hold the power button

Comment: @StackQsUp in recovery it works. en0 interface active, auto connected to my wifi and got dhcp address

Comment: Then it sounds like an issue with your configuration. Have you tried forgetting the Wi-Fi and reconnecting with default settings?

Comment: Wait, are you trying to manually assign an IP address, instead of using DHCP?